# How do I use MsiGetProductInfo to get installed version number c# winforms 4.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I'm trying to get the installed version number of my win fomrs application using the MsiGetProductInfo function. I am try to alter code i found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414653/get-install-date-from-managed-code), but all I get is wing ding looking text when I alter my call to the function like so

```
MsiGetProductInfo("{9806C9BE-59D4-4DEE-802F-0E492023DE8A}", "INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING", builder, ref len);
```

Its a 4.0 c# Winforms project that is installed with a standard vs2010 setup project. The client machines are win 7 and win XP

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but I recently had a similar issue, the fix is to change "INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING" to "VersionString"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the return value of the function? If it returns an error, it's possible that the buffer is filled with garbage.

This is a list of the possible returns, from the MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Return Value

ERROR_BAD_CONFIGURATION
The configuration data is corrupt.

ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
An invalid parameter was passed to the function.

ERROR_MORE_DATA
A buffer is too small to hold the requested data.

ERROR_SUCCESS
The function completed successfully.

ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT
The product is unadvertised or uninstalled.

ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROPERTY
The property is unrecognized.

Note  The MsiGetProductInfo function returns ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROPERTY if the application being queried is advertised and not installed.